# Is there any visualization tool available for OData?

Tags: odata

I am looking for a visualization tool for OData similar to XOData by Pragmatiqa. I need it to test and play with an OData service on my local machine. Pragmatiqa had a Chrome App had everything I am looking for but they seem to have discontinued it since it is not available on Chrome Store anymore.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you figure something out?

Answer (score 0):

I never got to use XOData but [JSON Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa/related?hl=en) seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

It appears some folks at SAP have created an `OData CSDL modeler` that can render `/$metadata` EDMX files as diagrams. Be sure to name your EDMX file with an `.edmx` extension.

It works in VS Code. Weirdly, I get errors for my `SAP Business One` OData .edmx file, as there are certain NavigationProperties it is failiing to parse just right, so, I guess I wasn't their target audience. Obviously YMMV

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SAPSE.vsc-extension-odata-csdl-modeler

Comment: Not worked for me, but promising tool for the job. Might be my edmx problem but the error message is so mysterious, talking about a webview.